# Get entity with all its child which meet a certain condition

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Just a disclaimer, this might have been already asked, but I didn't really knew what to search for.

So basically I have the following model:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UniqueName { get; set; }

    public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say I want to get a car which's `UniqueName` equals `Bentle`, but only with `Features` which cost less then 100$.

I could do something like this:

```cs
var car = DbContext.Cars.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.UniqueName == "Bentle");
car.Features = car.Features.Where(x=> x.Price <= 100).ToList();
```

This indeed works, but it seems to me as a lot of unnecessary conversions. Is there any way to shorten this Query?

#### A few Requirements:

- I need the `Car` Entity itself
- The List of `Features` only contain `Features` which cost less then 100$

Comment: Well, apart from not checking `car` to have `null` value your code seems ok to me. We get the car, we get its `Features` and filter them. The only 'conversion' we do is that we create a copy of filtered `Features`. If this query leads to performance issues, is a bottle-neck of your app you might want to consider to move this call to a stored proc.

Comment: Well I want to execute the whole query on my Database. For what I understand only the first line (FirstOrDefault) will get executed on the Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't see any unnecessary conversion in your query, but you can try the following if you want to execute your request in one line:

```
var car = DbContext.Cars.Where(x=> x.UniqueName == "Bentle").Select(car =>
          new Car()
          { 
            Features = car.Features.Where(x=> x.Price <= 100),
            .
            .
            /*here copy the remaining properties of car object*/
          }).FirstOrDefault();
```